# How to repeat a function a specific number of times until stopped

Tags: javascript, html

SO YEAH WOW... LOOKING BACK ON THIS. WOW. IT WAS SO SIMPLE IT'S CRAZY LOL

```
function start() {
  if (button.value == "ON") {
    // something to start repeating a desired function said amount of times here... or something
  }
}
```

**I'm a beginner coder :) &**
**I have *no* clue what to do**

Comment: javascript timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to do it:

```js
/**
 * How many times to repeat the function.
 */
const repeatAmount = 100;

function repeatFunc(curIndex) {
  console.log("REPEATED " + curIndex);
}

for (let i = 0; i < repeatAmount; i++) {
  repeatFunc(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you study up on the basic javascript constructs. One you should be familiar with is a `for` loop. For example:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  // Do the code here 100 times
}
```

can be used to repeat something 100 times.

Comment: Hey @JavaBruhipt, if you are looking for something else it would help if you could expand on what you are looking for in your question. A `for` loop is arguably _the_ standard way to "repeat a desired function said amount of times". There are other looping constructs (e.g. `while`) but without any more information I won't be sure how to help. Also, if you found this answer helpful, please upvote and accept.